# Android FragmentStatePagerAdapter - Missing view

Tags: android, fragmentstatepageradapter

I have created a set of horizontal tabs and for each tab content it has a View pager which in turn allows the content of the view to be swiped.

I am currently harcoding this to 3 views in the adaptor and returning a new inner fragment which represents the detail whenever getItem() is called.

This works fine until I navigate to another tab and when I go back the middle view is missing, this happens on all of the tabs.

When I look at the debugging I only ever see a call to getItem for positions 0 and 2, there is always a view missing though and so instead of the rendered view I just no layout there, if I swipe i get a another view.

If I dont click another tab but just keep swiping through the views in tab one which is the default then I dont lose a view, it seems to be only be when I have clicked to go to another tab and then back again. I never see a request for view in position 1 though, only ever 0 or 2.

my adaptor is an inner class of the fragment which represents the ViewPager and looks like:

```
public class HomeAddressDetailFragmentStatePageAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

    public HomeAddressDetailFragmentStatePageAdapter(FragmentManager fragmentManager) {
        super(fragmentManager);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 3;
    }

    @Override
    public android.support.v4.app.Fragment getItem(int position) {
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "requesting tab view in position: " + position);
        android.support.v4.app.Fragment fragment = null;

        fragment = new HomeAddressDetailFragment();

        return fragment;
    }
}
```

The onCreate for the fragment:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View rootView = (View)inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home_addresses, container, false);
    HomeAddressDetailFragmentStatePageAdapter homeAddressDetailFragmentStatePageAdapter = new HomeAddressDetailFragmentStatePageAdapter(getFragmentManager());
    homeAddressViewPager = (ViewPager)rootView.findViewById(R.id.home_addr_pager);
    homeAddressViewPager.setAdapter(homeAddressDetailFragmentStatePageAdapter);

    return rootView;
}
```

And the xml for this fragment:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
  <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/home_addr_pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1">

  </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
</FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is by default. **FragmentStatePagerAdapter** keeps two of the Fragments loaded at any time.

In your case:

- position 0 and 1

**OR**

- position 1 and 2.

Meaning fragment at position 1 is always 'there'.

You could (because you have 3 fragments), tell your `ViewPager`, to load more than two fragments at a time

```
homeAddressViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(2);
```

this way, your fragments will not be reloaded (by default offScreenPageLimit is set to 1).

> `setOffscreenPageLimit(int number)`
>
> Set the number of pages that should be retained to either side of the current page in the view hierarchy in an idle state.

But... it would be better to save your fragments state when the adapter does not need it, and reload it when it becomes visible again (for example by using `onSaveInstanceState`)

**UPDATE:**

as discused your work flow would be something like this. You send a request to get all addresses, parse them in ArrayList, and each Fragment should be a representation of one entry from your ArrayList.

The best way would be that you pass your parsed ArrayList to the adapter, and when calling `getItem()`, pass the ArrayList entry to the bundle (so you can access it in your Fragment).

```
public class HomeAddressDetailFragmentStatePageAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
    private ArrayList<Address> arrayListAddress;
    
    public HomeAddressDetailFragmentStatePageAdapter(FragmentManager fragmentManager, ArrayList<Address> arrayList) {
        super(fragmentManager);
        arrayListAddress = arrayList;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return arrayListAddress.size();
    }

    @Override
    public android.support.v4.app.Fragment getItem(int position) {
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putSerializable("address", arrayListAddress.get(position));

        android.support.v4.app.Fragment fragment = new HomeAddressDetailFragment();
        fragment.setArguments(bundle);

        return fragment;
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok well my next hurdle will be to back the tabs up with a network call to grab the real nmber of addresses and then fix it to this, so should I always set the method above to 1 less than the number of items in my arraylist of addresses?

Comment: Also if opsition 1 is always there why doesnt it render the actual view layout?

Comment: In fact it would be better if I could ask the view pager not to maintain any views I guess as then each time a view is requested I can just grab the data from the array for that item position and then render the data. is that a bad idea?

Comment: For **n** number of fragments, you should rather save the fragment state and restore it (for example by using `onSaveInstanceState`). Do not setOffscreenPageLimit to **n-1**, that would be bad. Position 1 probably renders, but only the first time when you create your adapter, not when you swipe.

Comment: If you are doing network grabs in every fragment, It would be better to save the downloaded data, and than when adapter is reloading your fragment, you should restore the downloaded data, not call the network request again (although that would work, but it would be unnecessary in my opinion)

Comment: I will be doing one network call to get the soap message, then parsing it as maintaining that somewhere, i havent worked that out, but I wont be making any more calls. I will then have addresses and temp addresses etc broken in in this case lets say array lists. I always want the screen to show item 0's data first then a left swipe would grab fragment 1 and populate it with address ones data and so forth, no more network calls but its just if I buffer the fragments somehow. Would an array within the HomeAddressDetailFragmentStatePageAdapter suffice?

Comment: I am not completly sure if I understand what are you trying to do... Does this workflow sounds like something you need? You will send a request to get all addresses, parse it in an ArrayList and than show one address from the ArrayList per Fragment? (each fragment will be one entry from the ArrayList/ one address?)

Comment: Ok, that shouldn't be a problem, ill update my answer with how the work flow should be.

Comment: Thank you you have helped me out a lot, I have been tasked with replicating an ios app in android so its been a bit of a learning curve!

Comment: No problem. I have edited my answer. Does that make sense to you? If not let me know and i'll try to explain.

Comment: No that makes perfect sense, thanks for the help I would be completely stuck without it. Cheers!

Comment: I know... I have been there, glad I could help you! :)